# select count(*) failing on hive / hadoop on windows

Tags: hadoop, hive

`hive> select count(*) from test_db.cust;`

```
Query ID = EMMAdmin_20200106222630_32064e30-7ae6-4e0a-bf1b-b0979e297102
Total jobs = 1
Launching Job 1 out of 1
Number of reduce tasks determined at compile time: 1
In order to change the average load for a reducer (in bytes):
  set hive.exec.reducers.bytes.per.reducer=<number>
In order to limit the maximum number of reducers:
  set hive.exec.reducers.max=<number>
In order to set a constant number of reducers:
  set mapreduce.job.reduces=<number>

Kill Command = C:\hadoop-2.10.0\bin\mapred job  -kill job_1578366054556_0003
Hadoop job information for Stage-1: number of mappers: 0; number of reducers: 0
2020-01-06 22:26:40,010 Stage-1 map = 0%,  reduce = 0%
Ended Job = job_1578366054556_0003 with errors
Error during job, obtaining debugging information...
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 2 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.MapRedTask
MapReduce Jobs Launched:
Stage-Stage-1:  HDFS Read: 0 HDFS Write: 0 FAIL
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 0 msec
hive>
```

error on Hadoop admin:

```
Application application_1578366054556_0001 failed 2 times due to AM Container for appattempt_1578366054556_0001_000002 exited with exitCode: -1 
Failing this attempt.Diagnostics: 
[2020-01-06 22:08:40.708]The command line has a length of 12995 exceeds maximum allowed length of 8191. Command starts with: "@set HADOOP_CLASSPATH=%PWD%;job.jar/*;job.jar/classes/;job.jar/lib/*;%PWD%/*;C:\apache-hive-3.0.0-bi "
```

normal select queries are working fine

`hive> select country from test_db.cust where first_name like 'S%';`

```
OK
USA
USA
USA
USA
USA
USA
USA
USA
Time taken: 0.229 seconds, Fetched: 8 row(s)
hive>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qdfKM.jpg)

Comment: what is the size of cust table ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is from commander.

You could use the next syntax, in order to output the result into a file:

```
hive -e "your query" > ~/sample_output.txt
```